# the category $\mathcal{A}$ of $R$-algebras on which $p^N=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to understand the following sentence:

> The category $\mathcal{A}$ of $R$-algebras on which $p^N=0$ for some $N>0$. Here $p$ is fixed prime.

What does represent here by $p^N=0$?

Does it mean that the $R$-algebras in $\mathcal{A}$ has a nilpotent element $p$?

If this is the case, then what does a $R$-algebra with $p^N=0$ for some $N$ give us more or less? What is the importance of the extra condition $p^N=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your algebra is unital (a very frequent assumption, especially in the areas you've tagged your post as), then you have $1$ in your algebra. You can add it to itself $p$ times, which gives you $p$. You can multiply $p$ by itself $N$ times to get $p^N$. You can ask if this is zero. If yes, then your algebra has $p^N=0$. (Put more high-mindedly, a ring $A$ being unital means there's a canonical homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to A$ sending $1\mapsto 1$ and we can identify any integer in $\Bbb Z$ with it's image under this map, and your sentence says that $p^N$ is in the kernel of this map $\Bbb Z\to A$.)

It may not be the case that $p$ is a nonzero nilpotent here: consider $\Bbb Z/p$, for instance. Here, $p=0$. (Typically when people ask about the presence of nilpotents, they really mean nonzero nilpotents: zero is trivially a nilpotent and zero's guaranteed to be in any ring or module by the axioms, so it's uninteresting.)

As for the importance, this is hard to say much about without more context (presumably you saw this sentence *somewhere* - it didn't just appear out of thin air to you). It's probably brought up because it is useful or interesting. Knowing you have multiple structures that play nice with each other on a ring/module/algebra/etc can be a very nice thing to have when solving a problem.